# menu items to load content into list from array jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to load the contents of several arrays into a list depending on what menu item is selected. here is a fiddle I made - was hoping someone could help me find out why the values are returning NULL http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/P47KZ/

Comment: I see your example but I don't quite understand what exactly is your problem. Can you specify?

Comment: the click event should trigger a specific array to be loaded into the <li>'s - see the if($(this).text() == vars[1]) it is saying if the text from the link matches the key value from the array then load it

Comment: Mmm...I think you need to clarify this even more. What should happen if I press "Player"? I can read the code, but you should tell us what is the expected behavior cuz maybe what's wrong it's precisely the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `populateCurrentData` method, `$(this)` doesn't refer to what you think it does - it refers to `window`. Pass `$(this)` into it as a parameter when you call it: http://jsfiddle.net/P47KZ/3/

Comment: OH MAN, thank you so much JOE if I had a higher rep I would 1 up you, please someone vote :)

Comment: Pah, that's no excuse to not 1-up me... oh, wait. Never mind :(